# How did Jesse run in an eight-like fashion without wearing the special speedster suit?

Tags: arrowverse, the-flash

In *The Flash* s3e3, named [*Magenta*](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Magenta), Jesse Quick, now a speedster, ran in an eight-like fashion to create enough upthrust to make the tanker float in the air till Barry convinced Frankie to come back in her senses.

What stings me is that Jesse ran *speedster*-ly without wearing the special suit other speedsters wear.

How could she do so?

The suit is designed to "withstand the high speed of movement" i.e., to protect the speedster from severe heating and other wears and tears experienced at such speed.

How could she run without wearing the special suit?

We have seen quite a few times though that Barry, too, also can run in his civilian dress without getting adversely affected.

So, the query should be re-aired as:

What is the point/necessity of the special suit if speedsters can do their job without it?

Or is it that speedsters can run comfortably at somewhat *not-so-high* speed without wearing the suit and that they need it only while going at *near the speed of light* or above?

Comment: mhhh, Earth-2 clothes maybe? ... but at the end of the episodes he is speeding with Iris in his arms and her dress didn't catch fire ... but when he saved Supergirl _her_ sweater caught on fire ... Felicity's shirt went up in flames ... we once saw Barry's shoes burning ... well, I guess the Speed Force works in mysterious ways.

Comment: I'd guess it was just the speed force protecting her. The show doesn't really seem consistent with this.

Answer (score 1):

In season 1 episode 1, we see that Barry ran all the way to Starling City (later renamed Star City), Barry seems to have run there without a suit, later on, we see Barry run onto the top of the building and take a picture of Felicity without a suit. In Flashpoint, when he was much faster, we see him run without a suit on occasion. So, my best guess is that speedsters can run without the special suit for a short amount at a time if they aren't going too fast. We see when Savitar reveals himself as a future time remnant that his face was burnt on one side, which was a result from him running too fast without a suit.